# Firestore seiralization problem with Release Build

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, release

I am using Firestore in my app and in debug version, everything works as expected. However, when using release version, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.*.*.h.g.f
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n0.j$a.<init>(Unknown Source:498)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n0.j.z(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n0.j.e(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n0.j.s(Unknown Source:147)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n0.j.p(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.o(Unknown Source:18)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.z.o(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.n(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.z.n(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.tnght.tnght.h.e.g(Unknown Source:54)
    at com.tnght.tnght.h.d.a(Unknown Source:13)
    at d.c.a.a.j.x.run(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

My app module build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tnght.tnght"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.jop
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.40.0'
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.9.0") {
        // Excludes the support library because it's already included by Glide.
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

My root project build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

According to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth
I've added SHA-1 of release version, but app still crashes on launch.
Any help?

Comment: Looks like proguard/minification might have stripped out stuff you need at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! Solved.

Answer (score -2):

As @Doug Stevenson said in comment, there was a problem with Minification. What i did is:

Change

```
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
```

To

```
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
```